# Transfering WhatsApp Data Between Two Phones

Tags: applications, whatsapp-messenger, data-transfer, google-drive

I recently had a problem while transferring my WhatsApp. I had lost access to my primary phone (Samsung Galaxy A71) for a while and had to use a secondary phone(Huawei P20). During that time I installed WhatsApp on my secondary phone but I did not use the Google Drive backup to restore the chats and instead started to use it as is. Now that I have gotten my primary phone back I was wondering how do I merge my WhatsApp data between the two phones on my primary phone because it already has the most data and the local storage and secondly I have to return the secondary phone as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

According to Google, there is some 3rd party software which will merge 2 WhatsApp backups. You will have to generate a backup file of both your installations.

[Here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/guide-merge-multiple-whatsapp-backup-file-into-one-no-root-required.3142974/post-66678565) is an extensive XDA forum post about it. [This](https://www.reddit.com/r/whatsapp/comments/hnaqpk/merging_two_whatsapp_backups_from_different/) Reddit thread proposes software which does it for you. I don't know the software though so be careful with your chat history.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).